# How do you post (share) a news item image and item;s url in the style of whatsapp?

Tags: android, google-chrome, post, android-intent, share

When you share a news item (from the chrome browser) into Whatsapp, usually what is posted is a thumbnail image together with the page URL, as shown below:

[image]

I am trying to replicate this behaviour in test app called Receive A Share 1.0

**The manifest is as follows:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" >

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">
    </uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.ReceiveAShare10"
        tools:targetApi="31" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            </intent-filter>
            
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
            
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            </intent-filter>
            
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**The MainActivity is as follows:**

```
package com.mo.receiveashare10;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.ClipboardManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView receivedImage;
    TextView receivedText;
    EditText typedInText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        receivedImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.received_image);
        receivedText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.received_text);
        typedInText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.type_in_edit_text);

        handleIntent(getIntent());
    } 

    public void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // if the intent action = ACTION_SEND and its MIME type = "text/plain" then display the text in the Text Received Box
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(intent.getAction())  && intent.getType().equals("text/plain")) {
            handleReceivedText(intent);

        } else if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(intent.getAction()) && intent.getType().startsWith("image/") ) {
            handleReceivedImage(intent);
        } else if (Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE.equals(intent.getAction()) && intent.getType().startsWith("image/") ) {
            handleReceivedMultipleImages(intent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        handleIntent(intent);
    }


    public void handleReceivedText(Intent intent) {

        Log.i("Receive A Share", "in the handleReceivedText() method");

        String sharedText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
        if (sharedText != null) {
            receivedText.setText(sharedText);
        }
    }

    public void handleReceivedImage(Intent intent) {

        Log.i("Receive A Share", "In the handleReceivedImage() method");

        Uri imageUri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);

        Log.i("Receive A Share 1.0", "The Uri from intent is : " + imageUri.toString());

        // Glide code:
        // Glide code:
        Glide.with(this)
                .load(imageUri.toString())
                .fitCenter()
                .into(receivedImage);
    }

    public void handleReceivedMultipleImages(Intent intent) {
        ArrayList<Uri> imageUris = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
        if (imageUris != null) {
            // update the UI to show the multiple shared images
        }

    }
}
```

The problem is that I don't get the image and the url link **at the same time**

**This is what I get in my test app:**

[image]

How can I replicate the behaviour of a whatsapp post ?
In other words how can I receive a share intent from the news website viewed in the chrome  browser from which I can extract the image **and** URL ?

I have searched and experimented long and wide without success. Any help would be very welcome !

Answer (score 0):

There are glaring mistakes in the code. I apologise - for example the if-conditions following the first if can never be tested. Also I have been carefully reading the documentation on action Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE and I think I have a solution to the problem which I will post when it is fully tested.